# I am unable to successfully submit guest entries

Tags: entries, guest-entries

I am trying to submit a guest entry it keeps returning a fatal error. This is my code

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="success">
<input type="hidden" name="profile" value="3">

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input id="title" type="text" name="title">

<label for="body">Body</label>
<textarea id="body" name="fields[body]"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/blob/master/README.md), you need to include a hidden `sectionId` field. This specifies the section to which the entry will be submitted.